# My old domain is getting more PR while new is at PR 0, Please help me understand this

Tags: google, pagerank

I am a web developer and I had a website for over 3 years, I mostly work local so no high traffic. Recently I started a blog on my website and around **2 months ago I got PageRank 1**.

After that I bought a new .com domain and move site to new domain and forwarded all traffic to new domain via htaccess file. Fine.

But **now my previous website had got PageRank of 2 but my new address still has PageRank  of zero**. Help me to understand this.

Comment: did You forward it with 301 code or 302?

Comment: I have done a 301 redirect. how can 301 affect the PR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The PageRank you see in your toolbar or other tool is stale information. While PageRank is updated regularly at Google they only update the toolbar PageRank periodically. This number is probably obsolete by the time the toolbar is updated so it can not be used to accurate find a page's true PageRank.
2. PageRank is **per page**, not **per website**. So your website never had a PageRank of 1. Your website's *home page* had a PageRank of 1.
3. If you didn't do 301 redirects from the old URLs to the new URLs then you are starting over in Google's eyes. Any PageRank you had for your previous pages is not "transferred" to their new URLs unless you do a 301 redirect. This tells Google that the page has moved and to update their rankings and "transfer" the PageRank to the new page. Some PageRank is lost but it is a nominal amount.

Comment: 1. I have checked PR with multiple sources. 2. Yes, I know its per page, my old webaddress homepage now has PR2. 3. I am doing 301 redirect.

Comment: 1. All of those sources get the same stale data. Only Google knows what your real PageRank is. 2. You need to clarify that in your question as the way you have it worded doesn't indicate that. 3. 301 redirects do not produce instant results. It will take weeks for you see the 301 redirects affecting all of your pages and then you still have wait to for Google to update their toolbar to see the effect it has had on your PageRank. So basically you have to wait.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody outside of Google can explain why or how Google does what they do. SEO "experts" can only speculate. Google has sealed up their trade secrets in a bullet-proof vault of legalese which is why they are the most successful search engine on the planet.

I would suggest to read up on Google Panda as it is their latest algorithm roll-out and has affected millions of websites in their index.